# I dont understand why every sub group of cyclic groups are also cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

This doesn't make sense to me. A group is cyclic if it can be generated by a single element. Let's say that the element is $\langle a \rangle$. since it is cyclic, at one point $a^n$ must be equal to the identity, where $n$ is a positive integer. but if a subgroup is cyclic, then its generator must also be powers of $a$, and $a^n$ must also be equal to the identity. so I don't understand how we can have a smaller sub-group than $G$, and it contains the same identity and still be cyclic if $a^n$ must be equal to the same identity for both groups. this just means that $n$ should be equal in both groups. and if $n$ is equal then you should have the exact same group

Comment: What is the subgroup generated by $3$ in the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$?

Comment: "one point a^n must be equal to the identity" This is false. Even if seems weird, the group of integers with the sum is considered a cyclic group with generator $1$

Comment: @EthanBolker {0,3,6,9,12} ( i think ).  I just kept multiplying {3n: n is an integer}: but how is this a subgroup of mod 15?

Comment: @jjagmath really? then why do we say the order of <a> is the smallest positive integer n, where a^n = identity

Comment: @user20194358 That is only true when the group is finite, $\Bbb Z$ is infinite

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout   . ok i see. so to be cyclic you just need to have a generator. thanks

Comment: @user20194358 Your calculation is correct. To see that it's a subgroup just check the definition of "subgroup".

Comment: As I say, at first is sounds weird, but yes, the definition of a cyclic group is one that is generated by one element. The [definition of the order of an element](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) is: the minimal positive integer $n$ such that $a^n$ is the identity, **if such integer exists, otherwise it's said to have infinite order**